# Insert table header dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a table header only once on to the top of a table. I have a code where I am able to generate header after inserting a row. I am missing the indexing here. where I am able to add header only after inserting the second row. Could you please help me fix a minor error here. I would not want to pass any object from html page.

```
var table = document.getElementById("Table");

            // Empty tables
            while(table.rows.length > 0) {table.deleteRow(0);}

            // Add rows
            for (var i = 1; i<data.Contents.length; i++) {
                var row = table.insertRow(i-1);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0), cell2 = row.insertCell(1),cell3 = row.insertCell(2),cell4 = row.insertCell(3),cell5 = row.insertCell(4),cell6 = row.insertCell(5),cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
                var cell8 = row.insertCell(7), cell9 = row.insertCell(8),cell10 = row.insertCell(9),cell11 = row.insertCell(10),cell12 = row.insertCell(11),cell13 = row.insertCell(12),cell14 = row.insertCell(13);


                //Code for header
                var header = document.getElementById("Table").rows[0].cells;
                header[0].innerHTML = " ";
                header[1].innerHTML = " ";
                header[2].innerHTML = "<b>NAME</b>";
                header[4].innerHTML = "<b>MODIFIED</b>";
                header[6].innerHTML = "<b>TIME</b>";
                header[8].innerHTML = " ";
                header[10].innerHTML = "<b>MORE</b>";     
                header[12].innerHTML = " ";      


                //column1: file icon
                var btn_fileIcon = document.createElement("input");
                btn_fileIcon.setAttribute("type","image");
                btn_fileIcon.setAttribute("src","images/file.png");
                btn_fileIcon.setAttribute("style","height:20px;width:20px");
                cell2.appendChild(btn_fileIcon);

                // column2: file name
                cell3.innerHTML =  data.Contents[i].Key.replace(folderName+'/', '');//data.Contents[i].Key;

                // Time
                var str = dateModified( data.Contents[i].LastModified);
                cell5.innerHTML = "  " + str;
                cell5.setAttribute("style","padding-left: 4cm");
                cell5.setAttribute("position","fixed");
                cell5.style.textAlign = "center";

                // size
                var s = Math.round( data.Contents[i].Size/1024);
                var fileSize = s.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                cell7.innerHTML = fileSize + " KB";
                cell7.setAttribute("style","padding-left: 4cm");
                cell7.setAttribute("position","fixed");
                cell7.style.textAlign = "center";

                // column3: download (csv)
                var btn_download = document.createElement("input");
                btn_download.setAttribute("type","image");
                btn_download.setAttribute("src","images/download-button.png");
                btn_download.setAttribute("style","height:20px;width:20px;margin-left: 100px;margin-right: 10px;");
                btn_download.setAttribute("onclick","load2local(this);");
                btn_download.fileName =  data.Contents[i].Key;
                cell9.appendChild(btn_download);


                // column4: delete
                var btn_delete = document.createElement("input");
                btn_delete.setAttribute("type","image");
                btn_delete.setAttribute("src","images/close-browser.png");
                btn_delete.setAttribute("style","height:20px;width:20px;margin-left: 10px;margin-right: 10px;");
                btn_delete.setAttribute("onclick","deleteObj(this);");
                btn_delete.fileName =  data.Contents[i].Key;
                cell11.appendChild(btn_delete);

                // load to NB
                var btn_load2NB = document.createElement("input");
                btn_load2NB.setAttribute("type","image");
                btn_load2NB.setAttribute("src","images/eye.png");
                btn_load2NB.setAttribute("style","height:25px;width:25px;margin-left: 10px;margin-right: 10px;");
                btn_load2NB.fileName =  data.Contents[i].Key;
                btn_load2NB.setAttribute("onclick","load2NB(this);");
                btn_load2NB.fileSize =  data.Contents[i].Size;
                cell13.appendChild(btn_load2NB);

                // checkbox
                var checkbox = document.createElement("input"); 
                checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
                checkbox.setAttribute("name", "all");
                checkbox.setAttribute("value", "ff");
                checkbox.fileName = data.Contents[i].Key;
                cell1.appendChild(checkbox); 
                checkbox.checked = false;   

                var element = document.createElement('hr');
                // element.setAttribute("style","border: 1px solid black;text-align: left; margin-left: 2%; margin-right:2%;");
                element.filename = data.Contents[i].Key;
                cell14.appendChild(element);                    
                }
```

Could you please help me to add a header once dynamically to a table?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to dynamically add table headers.

```html
<html>
  <script>
 const tableHeaders = ['My Header1','My Header2','My Header3','My Header4'] // your header titles go here

 function createNewTableHeader(headerTitle){
  const temp = document.createElement('th');
  temp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(headerTitle));
  return temp
 }

 function addHeader() {
  var tableHeaderPlaceHolder = document.getElementById('table-header-place-holder');
  tableHeaders.forEach(header=>{
   tableHeaderPlaceHolder.appendChild(createNewTableHeader(header));  
  }) 
 }

 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  addHeader();
 });

</script>
<body>
 <table id='table'  cellspacing="20">
  <tbody>
   <tr id='table-header-place-holder'>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>data1</td>
    <td>data2</td>
    <td>data3</td>
    <td>data4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>data1</td>
    <td>data2</td>
    <td>data3</td>
    <td>data4</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would not pass any element from html. is it possible to change my code to dynamically add the header and to keep the responsive design

Comment: What do you mean by "I would not pass any element from html" ?. If you're worrying about being responsive, it's up to you to modify the `createNewTableHeader` function to return the kind of elements to support responsive design.

Comment: in terms of td . As you can see in my code i have tried to add td using javascript.

Comment: The `td`s are here so you can see the whole table. Since you're asking how to add the **header** dynamically, I only provide the code to do just that. In my script, the header tags `th` will be created dynamically using javascript. My code doesn't add the `td` dynamically because you didn't ask for that. If you only need the headers, you can just omit the 'td's part in my script.

Comment: yes, the header should be dynamically generated for the existing td contents. I am already generating here dynamically. The only issue is with the indexing of the row. When I insert 2nd row only then the header will append to the first row removing the actual content in the first row.